# how to send Camera video using flash socket 

Tags: flash, sockets, video

this is my  flash as3 code :

```
var cam:Camera;

cam= Camera.getCamera();

var video:Video=new Video(200,200);
video.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(video);
```

use this code , i can see my Camera in this swf file ,

now i want to send/get this video to my friend using flash socket ,

so , i would create a client file and a server file using flash socket ,

how to create this client/server file ,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to user `flash.net.Socket` instead of simple `flash.net.NetStream`? Why?

I would recommend NetStream, see [NetStream.attachCamera()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#attachCamera%28%29)

You can use server publishing (FMS, Wowza, Red5), P2P direct connection or P2P NetGroup (with Adobe Cirrus), or just LAN P2P with NetGroup IP multicast (works without internet connection).

More inspiration on Tom Krcha's blog [flashrealtime.com](http://www.flashrealtime.com/p2p-chat-with-netgroup-in-flash-player-101/)